# how Pass data to angular material bottomsheet

Tags: angular, angular-material, bottom-sheet

I use Angular Material and Angular 6.
I work a lot with material dialog and i make like this :

```
openDialog3(key : string): void {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PPSDialogRemoveComponent, {width: '1000px'}); 
  dialogRef.componentInstance.key = key;
}
```

Now i want to work with angular materialbottomsheet. To pass the key, to my bottom component i try this :

```
  openBottomSheet(key: string): void {
    let dialogRef = this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.key = key;
}
```

But i have this error

> ERROR in src/app/geo/geo.component.ts(568,15): error TS2339: Property 'componen
>   Instance' does not exist on type 'MatBottomSheetRef'.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentInstance property will be applicable only to Dynamic Components which Created using ComponentFactoryResolver method and inserted into the DOM using ViewContainerRef.

As per the Angular Material Doc, dialog.open returns references of the model popup. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Comment: How i can pass my id in the bottomsheet ?

Answer (score 40):

Copy From [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/): Sharing data with the bottom sheet component.

If you want to pass in some data to the bottom sheet, you can do so using the data property:

```
const bottomSheetRef = bottomSheet.open(HobbitSheet, {
  data: { names: ['Frodo', 'Bilbo'] },
});
```

Afterwards you can access the injected data using the MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA injection token:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'hobbit-sheet',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.names }}',
})
export class HobbitSheet {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

Note: Version of Angular Material is v7.0.3

Check this out: 
 [Sharing data with the bottom sheet component](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview#sharing-data-with-the-bottom-sheet-component-)

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful for someone. I needed to add a small table to a bottom sheet so expanding on @YenYees answer:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetRef} from '@angular/material';
import {MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'bottom-sheet-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['bottom-sheet-overview-example.css'],
})
export class BottomSheetOverviewExample {
  constructor(private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) {}

 ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'}
];

  openBottomSheet(): void {
    this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet, {
  data:  this.ELEMENT_DATA ,
});
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet',
  templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html',
  styleUrls: ['bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.css'],
})
export class BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any, private bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet>, ) {}
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["position", "name", "weight", "symbol"];
  dataSource =  this.data;

  openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

with bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html as

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

In [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v53acg)